# Show that $(E|X|^{p_1})\leq (E|X|^{p_2})^\frac{p_1}{p_2}$, where $0<p_1<p_2<\infty$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. for $h\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$, define $Eh(X)=\int h(X)d\mu$.

Show that $(E|X|^{p_1})\leq (E|X|^{p_2})^\frac{p_1}{p_2}$, where $0<p_1<p_2<\infty$

Further show that equality holds iff $|X|$ is constant a.e.

I honestly don't have a good handle on how to start this one.

I sort of want to use jensen's inequality, but $x^{p_1},x^{p_2}$ aren't convex if $p_1$ or $p_2$ are less than $1$. Even if this could be remedied by multiplying  by a negative, it's not clear how to proceed. The fact that $\frac{p_1}{p_2}<1$ seems relevant, but I don't see where exactly that could be relevant to this problem.

I considered trying to show that $(E|X|^{p_1})^{p_2}\leq (E|X|^{p_2})^{p_1}$, but that didn't really get me very far.

Any thoughts suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = |x|^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}$. Note that $\phi$ is concave due to $p_1\leq p_2$. Then
$$E|X|^{p_1} = E\left(|X|^{p_2}\right)^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}} = E\phi\left(|X|^{p_2}\right) \leq \phi\left(E|X|^{p_2}\right) = \big(E|X|^{p_2}\big)^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}$$
by Jensen's inequality and the fact that $-\phi$ is convex.

Comment: Where you have $... = E\phi(|X|^{p_1})\leq...$, was that supposed to be a $p_2$ in there? Otherwise this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for being attentive.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a special case of the generalized Hölder inequality $\|XY\|_r\le\|X\|_s\|Y\|_t$ ($r^{-1} = s^{-1}+t^{-1}$) with $Y=1$, $r=p_1$, and $s=p_2$ (so that $t=sr/(s-r)>0$).